# Cannot get list of iOS simulators in Debug Target from Visual Studio 2022 on Windows

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2022

I have the problem that I'm not able to see the list of iOS simulators in Visual Studio Debug Target on my Windows PC

I've just made a total upgrade of my Xamarin development environment including now latest VS 2022, latest OS on my Mac, latest XCode version 14 and latest version of Xamarin on my PC and Mac. I have successfully paired to my Mac from Visual Studio.

On my Mac I've just tried to refresh the list of Debug devices as described in Microsoft Docs:

Delete your ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices folder.
Run killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService.
Run xcrun simctl list devices.

.. but still no result. All I can select in my Debug Target is Local Device, Remote Device and Simulator.

Before this upgrade I had no problem seeing all the simulators.

I will really appreciate if anybody have some good ideas of what I can do to solve this.

Following is my list of installed components from VS About box:

Xamarin   17.3.0.296 (d17-3@a0ff24b)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   17.3.0.208 (remotes/origin/d17-3@e4f67afef)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   17.2.28 (9b3d244)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   15.12.0.2 (87f98a75e)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954 check out this thread. But essentially you fucked up by updating Xcode 14.

Comment: I have the same issue with a slightly different setup: latest VS2022, Mac Monterey (13), XCode 13.4.1, no list of simulators in VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be noted that `XCode 14` is not yet supported in `Xamarin.iOS` or `.NET MAUI`, you need downgrade your Xcode version to 13.4.1 and could download it from the [downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) page in the Apple Developer Portal. For more information, you can refer to https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954

**Update:**

`Xcode 14` is currently supported and if there are any other issues, please continue to post back to [the GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954).Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alexandar .. downgrade XCode fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I have this same issue even after installing VS 17.3.6. I have no list of iOS simulators and I get a warning that this version of Xcode is not supported.